# Alternative to make primary key column varchar(max)

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a JPA entity which has a string `@Id` and the length of that id can be very long (6000 or more) in some cases I tried

```
 @Id
 @Column(name = "ID")
 @Lob
 private String id;
```

But after trying I came to know I can't make it `varchar(max)` in SQL Server (I don't know about other databases).
Now I want the a solution for this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Best practice is not to have a long string as your PK - instead an  `int` is more normal.

Comment: What entity has such a long string as a natural key?

Comment: It is for cache key @DanGuzman. But its in two three special cases.

Answer (score 0):

If the expected length of ID is long better is to use a simple auto-increment integer column as primary key. The reason to do that is to avoid processing overhead, when using Joins on that Key.

Answer (score 0):

You should guaranty in some ways that your id is unique
but using simple string field though it's long one, is not guaranteed to be unique
that's the reason why Databases offering GUIDs.